# Excel formula to compare two columns of names and put the matching ones in adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two columns with names.  I want to find the matching names in the two columns and put them in cells next to each other.  How can I do that?

Comment: Use the `MATCH` worksheet function, using `0` as the last parameter, e.g. `=MATCH("A1";"A2";0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try, in cell C1 :

```
IF(A1=B1,True,False)
```

this does assume a 1:1 equivalence of the two columns...
Or

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B$1:B$10,0),"")
```

this will find the contents of A1 in cells B1:B10 and they don't need to be sorted. If the object is not there then the result is blank, if it is there then the result is the position of the item in the list.

This will put the matched value:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$10,MATCH(A1,B$1:B$10,0)),"")
```

All can be dragged down...